# Does Automapper's `ProjectTo` work with `Expression` parameters

Tags: mapping, automapper

#### The "why"

I have a rather long and nasty **query**, used to map composite data.

The project setup is such that **AutoMapper** configurations are held inside the **ViewModels**. Since my query is long and involves quite a lot of business logic, which could potentially be reused, I would love to extract that in a **service**.

#### My attempt

Knowing that `ProjectTo` supports an `object parameters` as second argument, I created an **Expression Property** in my service like this:

```
Expression<Func<User, IQueryable<string>>> Filter { get; }
```

and passed it as parameter to AutoMapper:

```
this.DataRepository.All().ProjectTo<ViewModel>(
    ConfigurationProvider, 
    new { filter = service.Filter })
```

`ConfigurationProvider` is the standard **AutoMapper** provider and `service` is - well - my service.

Mapping method inside the **view model** looks like this:

```
Expression<Func<User, IQueryable<string>>> filter = null;

configuration.CreateMap<User, ViewModel>()
    .ForMember(
        m => m.MyProperty,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(filter));
```

It's textbook example, as provided in  [AutoMapper docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html?highlight=parameters#parameterization)

#### Result

This exact method worked before, when I was passing `IQueryable<Entities>`, however `filter` variable simply stays `null`, if I try to pass in my **Expression**. This obviously results in null value after mapping.

Why wouldn't **AutoMapper** resolve an **Expression**?

Comment: Well, it looks good, but it will never work :) Customizing the query itself is a lot more complicated than that. What you can do is write a function that returns an expression and call it wherever you need it.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for the input. Could you elaborate on how is having an *expression property* different from invoking a *method* with *expression* return type?

Comment: Think about parameters in SQL, they allow you to change the value of a parameter placeholder in the existing query, not the query itself.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu What I don't understand is why *method* would work. Both *method* and *Property* should be evaluated at run-time, however the *property* holds my expression, while the method should be executed at run-time to produce the expression. I don't understand how this is better for SQL translation.

Comment: I didn't say you can modify the query with an expression parameter. I said you can reuse an expression by reusing a method that generates an expression.